# Android: Mini_Kind and Macro_Kind

Tags: android, image, mediastore

May be a simple question.

Will the thumbnail of Macro_Kind and Mini_Kind be different on different set of devices e.g. tablet and phone?

Answer (score 0):

Nope. It's predefined sizes (in pixels):

`MINI_KIND`: 512 x 384 thumbnail `MICRO_KIND`: 96 x 96 thumbnail

[Thumbnails](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.html)